# Unable to return index with filter method JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, filter

I'm trying to return the index of an element in an array if it is a vowel, I'm unsure as to why I am unable to return the index with my code as it stands, the mdn states that the filter method should be able to return the element, elements index, or the name of the array so I'm a bit confused as to why I'm not able to do what I want, would someone be able to help me or at least break down why I can't do this?

here is my code below as well as a screenshot of what is being returned. I appreciate the help in advance

```
function vowelIndices(word) {
    let result = word.split('').filter((element, index) => {
        if (element.toLowerCase() === 'a' ||
            element.toLowerCase() === 'e' ||
            element.toLowerCase() === 'i' ||
            element.toLowerCase() === 'o' ||
            element.toLowerCase() === 'u' ||
            element.toLowerCase() === 'y') { return index + 1 }
    })
    console.log(result)
    return result
}
vowelIndices("apple")
```

Comment: That's not what the filter method is for. Filter returns a new array containing all the elements for which the callback function returned a truthy value. Use `findIndex()` to get the index of an element that matches a condition.

Comment: In this case, the screenshot doesn't convey any useful information. You thought to provide an [mcve] (thanks for that), which is all that's needed in terms of code. [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should be used to illustrate visual problems or requirements, such as layout issues.

Comment: MDN states that the callback passed to `String.filter` *receives* the element, index and array, not that it can return any of them. It says of the callback's return value: "Return a value that coerces to true to keep the element, or to false otherwise."

Comment: Why are the indices incremented?

Comment: What is this for?

Answer (score 0):

filter works differently , in each iteration of filter function you can return one boolean if its true it will be stored and ignored if you return false
lets see an example

```
let arr = ["apple" , "mango" , "banana" , "pinapple" , "orange"]
let res = arr.filter(each=>{
    if(each == "apple" || each == "mango" || each == "orange"){
        return true
    }
    else {return false}
})
console.log(res) // output [ 'apple', 'mango', 'orange' ]
```

now to find vowels you can use foreach or reduce **reduce is a bit difficult to understand at first**

```js
let test = `I'm trying to return the index of an element in an array if it is a vowel, I'm unsure as to why I am unable to return the index with my code as it stands, the mdn states that the filter method should be able to return the element, elements index, or the name of the array so I'm a bit confused as to why I'm not able to do what I want, would someone be able to help me or at least break down why I can't do this?`

// with foreach function
function findVowel(str){
    let res = []
    str.split("").forEach((each,i)=>{
        if(each.match(/[aeiou]/i)){res.push(i)}
    })   
    return res 
}

// with reduce function
function findVowel2(str){
    return str.split("").reduce((acc,each,index)=>{
        if(each.match(/[aeiou]/i)){acc.push(index)}
        return acc
    },[])
}

console.log(findVowel(test))
console.log(findVowel2(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example, the function `locateChars(text, ...terms)` can return indexes of matches for any type of string and/or array of strings.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
const data = "here is my code below as well as a screenshot of what is being returned. I appreciate the help in advance";

/**
 * Given an array of strings or a string, and one
 * or more strings to match against, return an array
 * of indexes. The indexes should correspond to
 * matches.
 * @param {array/string} text - An array of strings
 *        or a string.
 * @param {string<rest>} ...terms - A rest parameter
 *        of one or more strings to find matches of
 * @return {array<number>} - An array of index numbers
 *         that corresponds to matches
 */
function locateChars(text, ...terms) {
  /**
   * If >text< is an array, .join() it into a string
   * >chars< is >text< string converted into an array 
   * of chars.
   */
  let chars = Array.isArray(text) ? [...text.join('')] : [...text];
  // Convert any uppercase chars to lowercase
  chars = chars.map(c => c.toLowerCase());
  /**
   * Compare the contents of >...terms< with each
   * char of >chars< and return only the index number
   * if there's a match
   */
  return chars.flatMap((chr, idx) => [...terms].includes(chr) ? idx : []);
}

console.log(locateChars(data, "a", "e", "i", "u", "y"));
```

Comment: Why map `toLowerCase`? Why not chain it before the call to `flatMap`?

Comment: That's totally feasible, but I placed that step separately because it gets difficult trying to comment on a single line with a chain of methods.

Comment: You can always put each chained call on a separate line, and intersperse comments between them. Even better would be to drop the `map` entirely and call `toLowerCase` before spreading the string into an array. You could also move the spread to outside the ternary, rather than repeating it: `[...(Array.isArray(text) ? text.join('') : text).toLowerCase()]`.

Comment: Thar's pretty slick, but it might be too much for a novice.

Comment: I'd argue it's as clear as the current approach, and simpler for not using `map`. If you want to break it down for clarity, you could separate out the string conversion (i.e. ternary expression), lower-case conversion and array conversion. The `[...terms]` is another unnecessary complexity (especially as it's performed for each character in `chars`) `terms` is already an array, so you could simply call `terms.includes`. However, that's `O(terms.length)`; better still would be to use a set.

Comment: I'd edit the post, but don't want to change your intent. Here's a fiddle illustrating some other possibilities: https://jsbin.com/wipasab/1/edit?js

Answer (score 0):

`Array.filter` can only include or exclude elements from the result–it cannot change them in any way. This is documented on the MDN page.

If you want to get the indices of elements that have some property, you must convert the array to a form that pairs indexes with elements. [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will do this, as will [`Array.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries). The difference in this case is than the result of `map` is an array, while `entries` is an iterator. The latter doesn't have a `filter` method, so you'd need to convert it to an Array with (e.g.) [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
word.split('').map((ch, i) => [i, ch])
// or
Array.from(word.split('').entries())
// or
[...word.split('').entries()]
```

At that point, you can use `filter` to select just the vowel entries, then `map` again to discard the characters, keeping just the indices.

Note that the vowel test is inefficient an inelegant. A better way would be to use a set, either a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instance or an object literal with the set elements as keys. For example:

```
const vowels = new Set('aeiouyAEIOUY');
...
    .filter(([i, ch]) => Set.has(ch))
```

### Alternate Solution: Regex

This is a case that a regex can handle quite well, given the minimal amount of context and simple character sequence to match (a single letter). It can even distinguish 'y' at the end of a word, which is the only position it should be considered a vowel. [`String.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll), with the right regex, can find all vowels. As with `Array.entries`, it returns an iterator, which will need to be spread so `map` can discard all but the indices from the matches.

```
[...word.matchAll(/[aeiou]|y\b/g)].map(m => m.index);
```

This also has the advantage of working not only on a single word, but any string of multiple words.